# GCC 4.7 istream::tellg() returns -1 after reaching EOF

Tags: c++, istream

The following code works with gcc 4.4.
But gcc 4.7 will give assertion failure.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string input("abcdefg");
    stringstream iss(input);
    ostringstream oss;
    oss << iss.rdbuf();

    assert (!iss.eof());
    (void) iss.peek();
    assert (iss.eof());

    // the following assertion will fail with gcc 4.7
    assert( streamoff(iss.tellg()) ==
            streamoff(input.length()) );

    return 0;
}
```

In gcc 4.7, if the istream has reached EOF, tellg() will return -1. no pubseekoff() nor seekoff() will be called
In gcc 4.4 it is not a problem.

Which is the supposed to be behavior, gcc 4.4 or gcc 4.7? Why?

Comment: A little confused.  Why isn't `iss.eof()` set after extraction?

Comment: It was fixed from gcc 4.6, here [is the bug report](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=26211).

Comment: That bug report does not have too much description. The files were changed are related with the current issue though. How did you associate that bug fix with the current issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to C++11 section 27.7.2.3p40,

> if `fail() != false`, returns `pos_type(-1)`

So gcc 4.7 has the correct behavior for the current version of C++ (assuming that `peek()` at end of stream causes `failbit` to be set, and it does during sentry construction, since `skipws` is set by default).

Looking at the wording of C++03, it is the same.  27.6.1.3p37.  So the behavior you describe in gcc 4.4 is a bug.

Answer (score 2):

To be precise, `eofbit` won't cause `tellg()` to return `-1`. But the fact that you read *past* EOF sets the `failbit`, and `tellg()` will return `-1` if `badbit` or `failbit` are set.

The solution is to clear the status flags before calling `tellg()`:

```
iss.clear();
iss.tellg();  // should work
```