# C++ istream tellg()/fail() on eof: behavior change; work-around?

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, istream

I upgraded my compiler from gcc-4.4 to gcc-4.8 and one project fails miserably stemming from the following (false) assumptions:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <assert.h>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    istringstream iScan;
    int num;

    //iScan.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);
    iScan.str("5678");
    iScan >> num;
    assert(iScan.tellg() == istringstream::pos_type(4));
    assert(!iScan.fail());
    assert(!iScan.good());
    assert(iScan.eof());
    assert(num == 5678);
    assert(false && "We passed the above assertions.");
    return 0;
}
```

On gcc-4.4, relevant assertions pass. On gcc-4.8, tellg() returns -1 and and fail() returns !false, apparently since it hit eof.

My target is MinGW 32-bit as shipped with Qt 5.1 (gcc-4.8).

Questions:

- Is the old behavior really in error, per [N3168](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2010/n3168.htm) or other? (Which other?)
- Is there a global, reliable, language-independent work-around? (I'm guessing not.)
- Is there a global, reliable, gcc work-around that spans versions?
- Even when I do the above unsetf(skipws), it still doesn't work on gcc-4.8. Isn't *that* incorrect behavior?

Further, various online compilers give different behavior. Is that a function of their lib?

- [compileonline](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp_online.php), which claims to be gcc-4.7.2, allows it even though other sources say behavior changed in 4.6.
- [stack-crooked](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/), gcc-4.8, shows the new behavior, and unsetf(skipws) seems to have no effect.
- [codepad](http://codepad.org/Kn8H2jgP) allows it. Can't tell version.

Other similar but not duplicate questions:

- [file stream tellg/tellp and gcc-4.6 is this a bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552876/file-stream-tellg-tellp-and-gcc-4-6-is-this-a-bug)
- [GCC 4.7 istream::tellg() returns -1 after reaching EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13732338/gcc-4-7-istreamtellg-returns-1-after-reaching-eof)

The body of code, with these assumptions running through it all, is large.

**Update:**  Here's a key part of the answer, which should work across all versions, all compilers:

```
// istream::tellg() is unreliable at eof(): works w/gcc-4.4, doesn't w/gcc-4.8.
#include <sstream>
#include <assert.h>

using namespace std;
typedef istream::pos_type   pos_type;

pos_type reliable_tellg(istream &iScan)
    {
    bool wasEOF = iScan.eof();
    if (wasEOF)
        iScan.clear(iScan.rdstate() & ~ios::eofbit); // so tellg() works.
    pos_type r = iScan.tellg();
    if (wasEOF)
        iScan.clear(iScan.rdstate() | ios::eofbit); // restore it.
    return r;
    }


int main()
{
    istringstream iScan;
    int num, n2;

    //iScan.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);
    iScan.str("5678");
    assert(!iScan.eof() && !iScan.fail()); // pre-conditions.
    assert(reliable_tellg(iScan) == pos_type(0));

    iScan >> num;
    assert(!iScan.fail());
    assert(reliable_tellg(iScan) == pos_type(4));
    assert(iScan.eof());
    assert(reliable_tellg(iScan) == pos_type(4)); // previous calls don't bungle it.
    assert(num == 5678);

    iScan >> n2; // at eof(), so this should fail.
    assert(iScan.fail());
    assert(reliable_tellg(iScan) == pos_type(-1)); // as expected on fail()
    assert(iScan.eof());

    assert(false && "We passed the above assertions.");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you seem to expect is probably wrong.  Both C++11
and C++03 start the description of `tellg` with "Behaves as an
unformatted input function[...]".  An "unformatted input
function" starts by constructing a `sentry` object, and will
fail, doing nothing and returning a failure status, if the
`sentry` object converts to `false`.  And the `sentry` object
will convert to `false` if the `eofbit` is set.

The standard is slightly less clear about whether reading the
number sets the `eofbit`, but only slightly (with the
information spread out over several different sections).
Basically, when inputting a numeric value, the stream (actually,
the `num_get` facet) must read one character ahead, in order to
know where the number ends.  In your case, it will see the end
of file when this occurs, and will thus set `eofbit`.  So your
first `assert` will fail with a conforming implementation.

One could very easily consider this a defect in the standard, or
unintentional.  It's very easy to imagine some implementations
doing the sensible thing (which is what you seem to expect),
perhaps because the original implementors didn't realize the
full implications in the standard (or unconsciously read it as
they thought it should read).  I would guess that this is the
case for g++, and when they realized that their behavior was
non-conformant, they fixed it.

As for work-arounds... I'm not sure what the real problem is,
that you're trying to work around.  But I think that if you
clear the error bits before the `tellg`, it should work.  (Of
course, then `iScan.good()` will be `true`, and `iScan.eof()`
`false`.  But can this really matter?)  Just be sure to check
that the extraction actually succeeded before you clear the
status.

Comment: So, reading one char ahead, as you say, is the spec unambiguous that the number ends without failure at eof?

Comment: At eof, even if you clear eofbit, calling tellg() will just set it again, won't it?

Comment: @JimB The standard is clear.  When converting a numeric value, characters are extracted until either end of file is encountered, or a character is seen that cannot be part of a number (of any type or base).  If this extraction process terminated because of end of file, the `eofbit` is set.  (This is described in section 22.4.2.1.2, stage 2 of paragraph 3.)

Comment: @JimB No.  `eofbit` is set because an attempt to read a character (with or without extracting it) resulted in end of file.  `tellg` doesn't attempt to read a character.  The `eofbit` is _not_ predictive.  It will not be set because the next read will see end of file, it is set because an attempted (internal) read of a character failed; a call to `streambuf::sgets`, `streambuf::sbumps` or `streambuf::snexts` has returned `EOF`.