# C++ File handling:ios::ate not working properly

Tags: c++

In the below mentioned code when i apply ios::out it works properly but the same is not in the case of ios::ate,it shows some position -1 in the file and writing is not possible into the file.

Secondly where is peek() function used.

Code:

```
int main ()

{
    char p[80];
    fstream file("text1.txt",ios::in|ios::ate);
    cout<<"Starting position of the file is "<<file.tellg()<<endl;
    getch();
    if(file.is_open())
        cout<<"file is open\n";
    else
        cout<<"file is not open\n";
    getch();
    file.seekp(0);
    while(file>>p)
    {
        cout<<p<<endl;
    }
    file.clear();
    if(file<<"Now if we add text to the file")//Not working
        cout<<"\n Data entry possible\n";
    else
        cout<<"\n Data entry not possible\n";
    file.flush();
    cout<<"\nThe current position of the file pointer is "<<file.tellg()<<endl;//Showing position -1
    file.clear();
    file.seekp(0);
    if(file.eof())
        cout<<"\n the eof\n";
    while(file>>p)
    {
        cout<<p<<endl;
    }
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Starting position of the file is 30
file is open
Now
if
we
add
text
to
the
file

Data entry not possible

The current position of the file pointer is -1
Now
if
we
add
text
to
the
file
```

Comment: According to C++11 section 27.7.2.3p40, `if fail() != false, returns pos_type(-1)`.  See this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13732338/gcc-4-7-istreamtellg-returns-1-after-reaching-eof?rq=1).Since the get pointer is at the end of the file, no wonder you got -1 for `file.tellg()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ate` does not imply `out` so if you want to write to the file you still need to use `out`

```
fstream file("text1.txt",ios::in|ios::out|ios::ate);
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning ios::ate simple sets the initial position at the end of the file. If this flag is not set, the initial position is the beginning of the file. Though this doesn't automatically mean you can write to it.